# iOS Notification Icon on Android Wear

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

Hello guys right now I am working on an iOS app and have a android wear device paired with my iPhone when I revive an notification from my app the notification on my watch only shows the standard android wear logo instead off my app logo does anyone know if I can make it too show me own app logo?

Comment: It has been over 4 years :) Have you found any solution yet? :)